# Improving a triply-recursive function

Tags: c++

I have to optimitze a code with a triply-recursive function. I know that these kind of functions might be really slow, specially when dealing with large numbers. I have tried to improve the following code by comparing it with an efficient code of Fibonacci, but I'm still stucked.

Could you give me some hints? How can I use a loop instead? Thanks in advance!

```
int f(int i) {
    if (i == 0) return -3;
    if (i == 1) return -1;
    if (i == 2) return  4;
    if (i == 3) return  8;
    if (i == 4) return 15;
    return f(i-5) + f(i-3) + f(i-1);
}

int main() {
    int n;
    while (cin >> n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) cout << f(i) << " ";
    cout << "..." << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ditch recursion, use a loop instead.

Comment: "I have tried to improve the following code by comparing it with an efficient code of Fibonacci", which obviously uses a loop. Maybe the question is not clear enough, so I have specified that I'm asking for a version with a loop.

Comment: Have you tried writing it yourself yet? If so, show us your code.

Comment: Use `switch` or a lookup table. This pile of `if` statements is a mess.

Comment: the big problem is the strange serial of values for 0 to 4, I don't see a logic. The code can be more clear using _unsigned int_, because if the value is negative, ouppps

Comment: First fill an array (`std::vector`) of size N. Then look at which range is needed to be kept to continue the iteration. so you can use this *circular buffer*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you might store result in `std::vector`:

```
int f(int n) {
    std::vector<int> res{-3, -1, 4, 8, 15};

    if (n < 5) return res[n];
    for (int i = 5; i != n + 1; ++i) {
        res.push_back(res[i - 5] + res[i - 3] + res[i - 1]);
    }
    return res[n];
}
```

Then to reduce memory foot print, you might use only last values of the array:

```
int f(int n) {
    int res[5] = {-3, -1, 4, 8, 15};

    if (n < 5) return res[n];
    for (int i = 5; i != n + 1; ++i) {
        const int fi = res[0] + res[2] + res[4];
        std::copy(res + 1, res + 5, res);
        res[4] = fi;
    }
    return res[4];
}
```

You might even avoid the copy with circular buffer and use of modulo.

```
int f(int n) {
    int res[5] = {-3, -1, 4, 8, 15};

    if (n < 5) return res[n];
    for (int i = 5; i != n + 1; ++i) {
        const int fi = res[(i - 5) % 5] + res[(i - 3) % 5] + res[(i - 1) % 5];
        res[i % 5] = fi;
    }
    return res[n % 5];
}
```

You might notice that `((i - 5) % 5) == (i % 5)`
and replace the computation by

```
res[i % 5] += res[(i - 3) % 5] + res[(i - 1) % 5];
```

Comment: That's just what I was searching for. Thanks @Jarod42 !!